# Call async method from ASP.NET validator handler

Tags: asp.net, async-await

I have red how to work with async method in ASP.NET application [example Async-ASP.NET](https://github.com/RickAndMSFT/Async-ASP.NET/blob/master/WebAppAsync/WebAppAsync/GizmosAsync.aspx.cs).

Now I need to call web serivce in `CustomValidator` on `ServerValidate` event and by the service result decide, if value is valid or not. Service method are asynchronous and I am not sure, how to handle this. If I use async void event handler, validation does not work properly, because validation message doesn't show up in case validation is not successful. It seems like  await does not await for result of web service nor ASP.NET doesn't await the validator to send response.

What is the proper way to solve this? Or how to use `RegisterAsyncTask` in validator event handler? Page is set to `Async="true"`.

Piece of my code:

```
protected async void cvWorkplace_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{    
    // do test call to sap
    var testResult = await PerformLabelServiceTestCallAsync(materialId, ddPlant.SelectedValue, workplaceName, UsersLanguage);

    if (testResult.HasError)
    {
        e.IsValid = false;

        // other stuff
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will immediately return and the calling code will be evaluating `e.IsValid` before it is set by `cvWorkplace_ServerValidate`.

`RegisterAsyncTask` is a method of the `Page` class, which is the base class of your page and you can call it from the `cvWorkplace_ServerValidate` method, which is a method of your page.

But, even if you register an asynchronous task, you won't get the result in the `cvWorkplace_ServerValidate` method.

The best way would be to register an asynchronous task that would set a field in your page class and render accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution I was thinking about. But in my case is too expensive for implementation, so I have chosen to call web service synchronously. Thank you.